# User has access to directory But not able to list files inside it

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, amazon-ec2

The user has access to the directory But the user is NOT able list files or go inside that directory.

output of getfacl:

```
getfacl: data/emp/social/AUTO123/
user::rwx
user:spidy:r-x
user:lisa:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
```

`lisa` or `spidy` are not able to access the directory `AUTO123`

Why `lisa` and `spidy` are not to access the directory?

Comment: Are the users allowed to enter the parent directories?

Comment: Yes till social user is able to navigate

Comment: There is nothing about "social" user in the question. Are *these particular users*, `lisa` and `spidy`, who experience problems, able to navigate into all parent directories?

Comment: Yes they are able to navigate till social. So when I do getfacl on data/emp/social/ I get this: 
user::rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x

Comment: This is totally devolved of context, are these local users ? What filesystem is this ? why do you have getfacl lines like 'user::rwx', where there is no username ?

Comment: @rowland, you do realize that `user::` line is the ACL rule that corresponds to the traditional permission bits for the user owning the file?

Comment: @ikkachu, no I didn't, mainly because I have never seen it like that, there has always been a username shown whenever I ran the getfacl command. That doesn't help with the rest of my comments though.

Comment: @RowlandPenny `user::` is a way to specify permissions for the file owner, whoever it is. Also, `group::` is the permissions for owner group.

Comment: Well, please actually *show* use `getfacl` for each entry in the directory path. And the error message which users get when they attempt to list directory AUTO123. Show also traditional `ls -l` output for them; I want to see owners of every involved filesystem object.

Comment: @NikitaKiriyanov It might well be, but I have never seen getfacl produce output in that format. You can set whatever permissions you like on a directory, but if a user cannot 'walk' the path, they are meaningless. There is very little context here, other than what the OP provided, what OS ? What filesystem ? How are the users connecting ? Are they known to the system ? I could go on.